# Top alignment/position of text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using `SwiftUI` and want to position a `Text` element at the top of the screen.

My code looks like as follows and the output is below. As you can see it is in the middle of the screen. Can anyone advise how to update the position? I have tried to add `alignment` properties with little or no success.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Spacer()` after the Text View to push it upwards.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot that part in my answer, haha glad you caught it.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to add alignment properties with little or no success.

Alternatively, you can use `frame` with the `.top` alignment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```